# opc ua simulation server connecting issue

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, opc-ua, opc

I am trying to connect **Prosys OPC UA simulation server** to **Influxdb 2**.

When I connect **Prosys Simulation Server** to **Influxdb 2** via using
`Telegraf` it shows

> Database creation failed: 401 unauthorized.

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: So how does SQL Server fit into this?

Comment: we can use sql server to connect opc ua to real time dase but  in my case There is no use of sql server

Comment: In that case please remove the tag. You only want to tags that reflect the experts you are looking for.

Comment: Please share the [[inputs.opcua]] section of your .conf
What are you using for security_policy and security_mode
And on Prosys OPC UA Server, what security policies are enabled.